# call a function when slideDown or slideUp effect has finished

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a simple dropdown list, I want when the user toggles the dropdown list to show or hide another div using the jquery method slideToggle, unfortunately, I am struggling to solve the problem.

**Expected:** *when the user clicks an icon it should show the list and hide another div (slideDown effect) when the user clicks again for closing the dropdown list (slideUp effect), I want to show the hidden* div.

```
 var link = $('.sprzatanie-link');

  link.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    list.slideToggle("fast", function(){
      console.log('do something')
      if("slideDown"){
        $('.dezynfekcja-dropdown').hide();
      }else if("slideUP"){
        $('.dezynfekcja-dropdown').show();
      }
    });
  });
```

I tried adding a callback function but I don't know how to check the slide effect if it's slideDown or slideUp.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/ doesn't seem to have the ability to distinguish which way the slide is going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once toggle finishes it basically hides or shows the element being toggled. So in the `complete` callback you can simply check if your element is shown or hidden.

```
 var link = $('.sprzatanie-link');

  link.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    list.slideToggle("fast", function(){
      // `this` refers to the DOM element being toggled.
      // We can use `is(":visible")` to check if it visible or not
      let isVisible = $(this).is(":visible");

      // show console message that tells us if element is hidden or visible
      console.log(this.innerText, ' is now ', isVisible);

      // use isVisible to do whatever you want show/hide etc
      if(isVisible) {
        $('.dezynfekcja-dropdown').hide();
      } else {
        $('.dezynfekcja-dropdown').show();
      }
    });
  });
```